# Using A Parametr (string) in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i'm trying Too use a listBox for Select the Search,
but i can't use the string si in LINQ, i don't know how use it,
i made this code, but don't know how use the si.

```
        var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        string si = "";
        if (selectedIndex == 0) si = "id" ;
        if (selectedIndex == 1) si = "name";
        if (selectedIndex == 2) si = "sex";
        if (selectedIndex == 3) si = "address";
        if (selectedIndex == 4) si = "phone";
        if (selectedIndex == 5) si = "web";
        var qsearch = db.users.Where(c => c.[i want use si in this place].Contains(textBox7.Text));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = qsearch;
```

Comment: You might want to consider using [Dynamic Linq Library](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/) (available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set the query in each `if` statement

```
switch (selectedIndex)
{
   case 0:
     dataGridView1.DataSource = db.users.Where(u => u.Id.Contains(...));
     break;
   ....
 }
```

Comment: What if the logic of your query changes slightly?  You now need to change it in 6 different places, and risk making a mistake for one of them, or having a copy-paste error and changing the wrong line's property, etc.  It's not effective maintain something like this.

Comment: Thanx, But when i try to Use ".Contains(...)" in switch, this is not usable.

Comment: "..." is just a convention for "insert code here".  You should replace "..." with `textBox7.Text`.

Comment: i know that, but i can't use this code ins switch, ".Contains(textBox7.Text)" it's unknown

Comment: What is "unknown".  Is it because `Id` is a non-string?  If so try using `ToString().Contains(...)` or `ToString().StartsWith(...)`.

Comment: oh, thanks, i forgeted that, because this is my first day i programming C# and LINQ, Thanks Man;